# Interact with page element found by regular document query selector in jest/RTL test

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I would like to be able to open a menu that opens when you click on a hamburger element. this element is set up by an external library. the RTL query functions aren't able to access it as it does not have any attributes to match against (no text, label text, role, title, etc.).

I can retrieve it with document.querySelector, but that function returns an Element, and I need to be able to fire a click event on it which requires the element to be of class TargetElement. is there a way to retrieve the element in that type, or otherwise convert it? I've tried

```
const MenuButton = document.querySelector("external-lib-classname") as TargetElement;
fireEvent.click(MenuButton);
```

But this does not seem to work with fireEvent as it does not recognize the element as a DOM element.

This seems to be a bit of an oversight on RTL, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a manual query on the `container` returned by RTL's `render` method.

```js
const { container } = render(<Component />);
const menuButton = container.querySelector("external-lib-classname");
fireEvent.click(menuButton);
```

Note that using `querySelector` to query by class/id is [not recommended by RTL](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#priority) and should only be used as last resort, when everything else fails.

Comment: Thank you very much! believe me, I've tried just about everything else. ag-grid is not the most compliant with RTL